# Any changes required on connection string when the database is move to a different drive?

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection-string

I'm planning on moving a database from C: drive to E: drive because the database is growing and the C: drive does not have enough capacity to handle that.

I wonder if I need to changes anything in the connection on the web.config page in order to access the database.

The database still has the same name, is still on the same server, only is moved to a different drive.

thanks,
aein

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are situations where the path to the database file is important (See the AttachDBFilename parameter [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx)).  However, if you don't currently have any file path information in your connection string you shouldn't need to make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Not needed. It does not impact the web app.